# Boost unit testing main function?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

How do I define my own `main()` function when testing with boost?

Boost is using it's own main function, but I'm using a custom memory manager and it needs to be initialized before any memory is allocated, otherwise I'll get errors.

Comment: In C++, `main` is not a method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I do not believe you actually need your own main. I think you are much better off with [global fixture](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/fixture/global.html):

```
struct AllocatorSetup {
    AllocatorSetup()   { /* setup your allocator here */ }
    ~AllocatorSetup()  { /* shutdown your allocator/check memory leaks here */ }
};

BOOST_GLOBAL_FIXTURE( AllocatorSetup );
```

Comment: For the OP's purpose, this seems most appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

You have to define

`BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN`

before the boost includes.

`BOOST_TEST_MAIN`

is the default.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/compilation.html

Answer (score 0):

You can define a static object and his constructor will execute before main:

```
class Alloc_Setup {
   Alloc_Setup() {
       // Your init code
   }
   ~Alloc_Setup() {
       // Your cleanup
   }
};
Alloc_Setup setup;
int main() {} // (generated by boost)
```

Comment: That's more of a hack than a solution, plus it doesn't allow you to define your own main function. No problem tough, I found the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Memory can be allocated before `main`:

```
static int* x = new int(1);
int main() { return *x; }
```

And you could make your memory manager a global variable as well,
but you can't enforce a specific order of global variables initialization. (in standard C++ at least)

In Windows you could put your memory manager into a DLL, at it will be initialized before application entry point will be called, but still, something other may allocate a memory before - another DLL, or CRT of your DLL.

Comment: The initialization order of globals is well defined inside a single compilation unit - so you _can_ enforce any order you want. Just place them in a single CU :)